# Can a class be a parameter to a method?

Tags: java, class, hadoop, parameter-passing

I have been trying to understand hadoop mapreduce programs since a few days. I saw the following statement.

```
conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
```

I dont challenge the legitimacy of this statement as the program runs without issues. Can someone explain why a TextInputFormat.class is the input instead of an object of type text input format? And can i use the same convention for other methods too? under what circumstances would it fail?

This is the signature of setinputformat.

```
<http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setInputFormat(java.lang.Class)>

setInputFormat(Class<? extends InputFormat> theClass) 

Set the InputFormat implementation for the map-reduce job.
```

Comment: Check out reflection for one application.

Answer (score 3):

The mappers and reducers need to know what *kind* of format.  They don't need an actual handle to it.  Each mapper/reducer will use that `Class` to instantiate their own using reflections.  It's the difference between giving someone a hammer and telling someone to use a hammer.  Your particular example is an instruction to use a hammer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can pass the class as a parameter.
Below is the short example how to pass class as a parameter:

```
public void foo(Class obj){
    Object ob = obj.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: is public void foo(Someclass obj){} same as public void foo(Someclass.class){}